# for-loop variable

Tags: python

```
for i in range(3):
    print(i)
```

Is i just considered a variable?  Which is updated each loop?

EDIT: I was 14 when I asked this, I am so ashamed.

Comment: I would recommend running through a structured tutorial, see e.g. https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F.

Comment: It's a variable.  It gets set to each successive value of the iterator, so that the value can be used in the loop body.

Comment: see https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Comment: `i` is just a label or name that you can use to refer to the value that comes out of range on each iteration of the loop. You could call have called this alsmost anything like `x` or `num` or `my_variable`

Answer (score 1):

> Range, by definition, returns an object that produces a sequence of integers from
>   start (inclusive) to stop (exclusive) by step.  range(i, j) produces
>   i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1. start defaults to 0, and stop is omitted!

So when you are iterating over the range(3) object, you are iterating over the sequence of integers it produces, and in your case, printing the integer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a variable. I recommend you to go through the basics, thoroughly, if you are a new bee.

You can take any variable, not just `i`.

```py
for a in range(3):
    print(a) # it will print 0,1,2
```

```py
for a in range(5,8):
    print(a) # it will print 5,6,7
```

```py
for a in range(0,10,2):
    print(a) # it will print 0,2,4,6,8
```

`range(3)` will produce an object, which can be iterable, that produces a sequence of integers and `for` will iterate the elements one by one.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(3):
    print(i)
```

means that `i` is a local variable (you can call it anything you want) that will have an initial value of 0, increment by one in each loop and stop at 3 - 1. You can check the tutorial here:
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter2/